# Not able to find Class using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-single-nosearch" style="width: 169px;" title="" id="activationTime_chosen">
   <a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
      <span>Select Time Slot</span>
      <div><b></b></div>
   </a>
   <div class="chosen-drop">
     <div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly=""></div>
     <ul class="chosen-results"><li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0">Select Time Slot</li></ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

In this Above code I want to insert a new **li** tag with contents, but im not able to find the class **chosen-results** selector to append the value

the code I used is

```
$('#activationTime_chosen .chosen-drop').find('.chosen-results').append('<li class="active-result" value="' + timeSlotEqualsSeperated[0] + '">' + timeSlotEqualsSeperated[1] + '</li>');
```

Comment: its working for me.

Comment: Same, works just fine for me, look here https://jsfiddle.net/z9stuwo1/

Comment: Probably you need to wait for document ready

Answer (score 0):

According to posted HTML structure, you are using jQuery Chosen plugin to power custom selectboxes. The way it works is that it dynamically populate `.chosen-results` container right before showing dropdown.

If you want to customise the dropdown list the simple way can recommend is to bind to `chosen:showing_dropdown` event and from there append new item to the list.

This should work for you:

```
$('#your-select-element').on('chosen:showing_dropdown', function(e, data) {
  var $container = data.chosen.container
  $container.find('.chosen-results').append('<li class="active-result" value="' + timeSlotEqualsSeperated[0] + '">' + timeSlotEqualsSeperated[1] + '</li>')
})
```